# Update Location action is always fired twice

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I'm using router-store.
On every route change, I see that the `[Router] Update Location` action is fired twice.
Is that normal ?

Comment: some code would help plz !

Comment: No, it's not normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug with the latest router (3.2.0)  switch to the 3.1.0 router.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12869#issuecomment-276950926